# Wordpress Posts - Ajax Load More Random Order, filter not working?

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am currently facing some issues with my function that loads more posts on my website. You see, by default, it displays the latest four posts on correct order. However, when I click the 'load more' button, it do show more posts, however, then it just stacks up in a random order.

I have been strugglig with this for nearly two days now, trying everything I've come across, and also gotten help from my friend that is in fact an experienced WordPress developer, and nor did he find a solution.

I did some research and I have tried to add the `'suppress_filters' = true` without any luck as well. So, here is my code so far.

This is the code that displays the default four posts, in the correct order:

```
<section class="posts-container">
        <div class="container">
            <h1 class="earlier-posts-title mt-5 text-center"><?php echo get_theme_mod('earlier_posts_title'); ?></h1>
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row mt-5 mb-5 misha_posts_wrap">

                    <?php if(have_posts()) : ?>
                    <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                    <div class="col-lg-6 mb-4">
                        <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()): ?>
                        <div class="thumbnail-container">
                            <?php the_post_thumbnail('', array('class' => 'thumbnail-post')); ?>
                        </div>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <h1 class="thumbnail-title mt-3 text-center"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                        <p><?php echo the_time(); ?></p>
                        <div class="meta">
                            <p class="thumbnail-meta mt-3 text-center"><i class="far fa-clock"></i> Skrevet den <?php the_time('j. F Y');?></p>
                        </div>
                            <p class="thumbnail-content-text text-left"><b class="text-left"><?php the_excerpt();?></b></p>
                        </div>
                        <?php endwhile; ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php endif;?>
                        <?php
                    global $wp_query; // you can remove this line if everything works for you
                    if (  $wp_query->max_num_pages > 1 )
                        echo '<div class="misha_loadmore">More posts</div>'; // you can use <a> as well
                ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

And here is the myloadmore.js:

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('.misha_loadmore').click(function(){

        var button = $(this),
            data = {
            'action': 'loadmore',
            'query': misha_loadmore_params.posts, 
            'page' : misha_loadmore_params.current_page
        };

        $.ajax({
            url : misha_loadmore_params.ajaxurl,
            data : data,
            type : 'POST',

            beforeSend : function ( xhr ) {
                button.text('Loading...');
            },
            success : function( data ){
                if( data ) { 
                    button.text( 'More posts' ).prev().before(data);
                    misha_loadmore_params.current_page++;

                    if ( misha_loadmore_params.current_page == misha_loadmore_params.max_page ) 
                        button.remove(); // if last page, remove the button

                    // you can also fire the "post-load" event here if you use a plugin that requires it
                    // $( document.body ).trigger( 'post-load' );
                } else {
                    button.remove(); // if no data, remove the button as well
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And last but not least, the functions.php file:

```
function misha_my_load_more_scripts() {

    global $wp_query; 

    // In most cases it is already included on the page and this line can be removed
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

    // register our main script but do not enqueue it yet
    wp_register_script( 'my_loadmore', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/myloadmore.js', array('jquery') );

    // now the most interesting part
    // we have to pass parameters to myloadmore.js script but we can get the parameters values only in PHP
    // you can define variables directly in your HTML but I decided that the most proper way is wp_localize_script()
    wp_localize_script( 'my_loadmore', 'misha_loadmore_params', array(
        'ajaxurl' => site_url() . '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', // WordPress AJAX
        'posts' => json_encode( $wp_query->query_vars ), // everything about your loop is here
        'current_page' => get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1,
        'max_page' => $wp_query->max_num_pages
    ) );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'my_loadmore' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'misha_my_load_more_scripts' );

function misha_loadmore_ajax_handler(){

    // prepare our arguments for the query
    $args = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['query']),true);
    $args['paged'] = $_POST['page'] + 1;
    $args['post_type'] = 'post';
    $args['order'] = 'DESC';
    $args['orderby'] = 'date';
    $args['post_status'] = 'publish';
    // it is always better to use WP_Query but not here
    query_posts( $args );

    if( have_posts() ) :

        // run the loop
        while( have_posts() ): the_post();

            // look into your theme code how the posts are inserted, but you can use your own HTML of course
            // do you remember? - my example is adapted for Twenty Seventeen theme
            echo '<div class="col-lg-6 mb-4">';
            echo '<div class="thumbnail-container">';
            the_post_thumbnail('', array('class' => 'thumbnail-post'));
            echo '</div>';
            echo '<h1 class="thumbnail-title mt-3 text-center">';
            echo the_title();
            echo '</h1>';
            echo '<div class="meta">';
            echo '<p class="thumbnail-meta mt-3 text-center"><i class="far fa-clock"></i> Skrevet den ';
            echo the_time('j. F Y');
            echo '</p>';
            echo '</div>';
            echo '<p class="thumbnail-content-text text-left"><b class="text-left">';
            echo the_excerpt();
            echo '</b></p>';
            echo '</div>';
            echo '</div>';

        endwhile;

    endif;
    die;
}

add_action('wp_ajax_loadmore', 'misha_loadmore_ajax_handler');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_loadmore', 'misha_loadmore_ajax_handler');
```

So according to my thesis, the problem lies in the misha_loadmore_ajax_handler in the functions.php file, because as soon I hit the load more button, all of the posts gets sorted in a random order. And you can also see that I have applied numerous filter in an attempt to fix this. I just want it to display properly.

The code is from Misha, with link here: https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/load-more-posts-ajax.html

I'm fairly new to WordPress development and PHP in general.

What am I doing wrong here? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

**only use 'suppress_filters' = true** without ordering in $args array.. 
(if need before sort - use pre_get_post)

```
$args = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['query']),true);
$args['paged'] = $_POST['page'] + 1;
$args['post_type'] = 'post';
$args['post_status'] = 'publish';
$args['suppress_filters'] = true;

query_posts( $args );
```